# Kohana 3.0.4 ORM $_created_column $_updated_column

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I have a problem in my model declaration, in Kohana 3.0.4 with the fields  `$_created_column` and `$_updated_column`.
The problem is that :
- When I create and update objects from my controllers, the fields in the database corresponding to  `$_created_column` and `$_updated_column` declaration are modified, according to the current create/modification date, just as it should be.

- When I create and update objects from the models (using `DB::insert`, `DB::update`) (this is the best practice -> handling data operations from models) the fields corresponding to the declaration are NOT updating.

The code for DB::update and DB::insert:

```
    public function add_productimage($zoom, $particular, $thumbnail, $presentation, $product, $order){   
    $insert_id = DB::insert('product_image', array('zoom','particular','thumbnail','presentation','product','order'))
        ->values(array($zoom, $particular, $thumbnail,$presentation, $product, $order))
        ->execute();
    return $insert_id;
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using **ORM** for inserts and updates, thus these specific settings are not applied. You use **DB Query Builder** instead of ORM. **Use ORM for inserts / updates** and you will be then employing best practice in this case.

By the way: your version of Kohana (`3.0.4`) should be easily updated to `3.0.12` (the most up-to-date in `3.0.x` line), and this will fix multiple bugs that existed in `3.0.4`.

Comment: so you say that using db:: in models is not best practice? i should be instead using the orm ?

Comment: If you are using ORM anyway, then why not to use it for saving? Another option is not to use ORM and go with pure DB Builder only but you loose a couple of great things ORM adds (like auto validation for example). In your case I'd go with ORM all the way.

Comment: okay, fair enough. thank you. upgrating to 3.0.12 doesn;t involve rewriting code?

Comment: @dana: No problem. When it comes to upgrading: it depends. Basically `3.0.12` should be compatible with `3.0.4` and should only fix bugs and other issues, but not change interfaces etc. So if you did not change anything in core of Kohana nor did you use some elements of Kohana that would rely on their incorrect behaviour, then it should not involve rewriting any part of your code. Even if it would, I would suggest switching to `3.0.12`, which fixes a lot of bugs. I am not suggesting switching to `3.1`/`3.2`, because this would involve rewriting some parts of your code (even if they are small).

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't see any reason not to use ORM inside your method:

```
public function add_productimage($post)
{
   $this->values($post);
   $this->save();
}
```

This is the preffered way to go, since this way you'll have your model validated before saving.

To answer your question - have you tried doing it exactly the same way as [docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/results#insert) say?
Oh and also make sure you point to the right table - in your example it's `product_image` while Kohana style is `product_images`. Maybe you forgot the add the 's' at the end.